# Maven dependency in a Gradle project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle

I'm developing a project with gradle. My build file is almost empty so far:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

version = '0.1'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

My project depends on a Maven project. Precisely this project: http://git.eclipse.org/c/bpmn2/tree/org.eclipse.bpmn2

I've cloned this project into my workspace, but I don't know the best way to declare the dependency in my build.gradle file. This is what I've done so far:

```
dependencies {
    compile files ("C:/path/to/org.eclipse.bpmn2-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar")
}
```

But this way I have to manually build the maven project. Does somebody know a better way of doing this dependency management?

I'm using [Eclipse Gradle Integration](https://github.com/SpringSource/eclipse-integration-gradle/wiki) and I've noticed an interesting eclipse project property:

```
Gradle - Dependency Management
[x] Remap Jars to maven projects (requires Gradle 1.1 and m2e)
```

This seems to do what I need. But I don't know how to use this feature...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [eclipse-integration-gradle plugin](https://github.com/SpringSource/eclipse-integration-gradle) replaces the mavenLocal() jar dependency with a Eclipse project dependency. This is the easiest way I've found so far. See: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?139634-How-to-use-quot-remap-Jars-to-maven-projects-quot-feature

Comment: Make note of Kris' comment there, specifically: *"...for the feature to work you have to publish the jar at least once to some maven repo."* I was pulling my hair out wondering why the local workspace resolution wasn't working, until I read that. Once I published the maven project 1 time to my local repo, then Gradle was able to resolve the copy in my workspace.

Answer (score 3):

If the Maven project is not available in any Maven repo, Gradle can't find it anywhere, so you'll have to build it. I would at least `mvn install` it, and tell Gradle to look for artifacts in your local Maven repo rather than in a specific directory, using

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
```

Comment: Yes, i've tried that, but install fails during a "sign" phase. But this is another issue. Anyway I wonder if there is some way to depend on Maven projects. I'll investigate further that "remap jars" property I've quoted.

Comment: There is no first-class Gradle feature to depend on a Maven build. Typically you'd exchange build outputs via the local Maven repository. Or better, via a more dedicated local or remote Maven repository that isn't also a Maven cache.

Comment: It's been almost 3 years, is this still true that these are the only options?